# How can you limit download speed using Rails or Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I have a ruby on rails app running on passenger / nginx.  The app allows users to have download access to very large files (VM backups, sometimes 200Gigs) and I'm on a burstable connection with my ISP up to 100 Mbit/sec.

The problem is that if you begin downloading one of these large files the transfer will climb as high as possible which I don't want.  I'd like to limit the downloading of these large files to a fixed rate such as 150 Kbps while still allowing faster speeds on other parts of the application. Is this possible?

Comment: to me it's a serverfault question. It's a nginx configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should include a directive like this in your nginx configuration file (inside the block of your server configuration):

```
limit_rate 150k;
```

This limits the speed of transmission of the answer to client. It works as a limit for each connection, not for the total server transfer rate. (Maybe you can adjust max_clients = `worker_processes` *  `worker_connections` as a work-around to limit total transfer.)

Take a look at nginx documentation for [limit_rate](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#limit_rate). There is also a `limit_rate_after` directive that is useful to set this limit only after download exceeds certain size.